# How to update fragments dynamically in viewpager android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I am working on one application which contains dynamic pages,so that i have taken viewpager.I created one fragment dynamically it creates,in that fragment i am calling webservice after success response i am refreshing data ,but fragment is not updating.I am using StatePagerAdapter.

code:

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    private ArrayList<InstituteVO> _instituteList;
    private ArrayList<CourseItemVO> _courses;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<InstituteVO> instituteList)
    {
        super(fm);
        _instituteList = instituteList;
        _courses=new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        PagerItemFragment fragment = new PagerItemFragment();
        fragment.setItemInfo(_instituteList.get(position), this);
       // fragment.setCourses(_courses);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return _instituteList.size();
    }
    public int getItemPosition(Object item) {

        return super.getItemPosition(item);

    }

public class PagerItemFragment extends BaseFragment implements OnWebServiceResponseListener,View.OnClickListener
{
    private RecyclerView _courseView;
    private CourseCustomRecycleAdapter _adapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.institute_pager_layout, null);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        setData();
    }

    private void setData()
    {

        callDataService(_item);
    }

    private void callDataService(String slug)
    {

        WebServiceController.getInstance().serviceGET(this, new InstituteProcessor(), url, AppConstants.METHOD_GET, slug);
    }




    @Override
    public void onWebServiceResponseSuccess(OnWebServiceDataProcessListener response)
    {
        if (response != null && response instanceof InstituteProcessor)
        {
            _adapter.setData(((InstituteProcessor)response).getInstituteVO().getCourses());
        }

    }

   }
```

Comment: how you are updating fragment ? are you calling notifydataset change ? I did see all this in code ? can you please post some more code related to refresh logic

Comment: is it required to refresh viewpager adapter

Comment: i am using same fragment,after calling webservice i am getting response in that response method should i call viewpager adapter notifydatasetchanged

Comment: Yes u need to call notifydatasetchanged

Comment: where should i call,if call pager adapter notifiydatasetchanged it will refresh whole data

Comment: I don't know how you are refreshing the data, but pager adapter notifydata set change you need to call to reflect the change in view pager fragment